# PHP/MySQL Deleting before interval

Tags: php, mysql, intervals

so I want my MySQL Row to delete when it's been 2 hours after being added by said user.

Here's what I have;

```
$Link = MySQL_Connect // etc

$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time())

$query = "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('unable to run: ' .mysql_error());
```

But when I run it, it's deleting every row even if it hasn't been 2 hours.

Incase this helps, My insert query;

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO my_table (name, email, time) values ('$Name', '$Email','$now')");
    echo 'Proceed';
```

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is to make sure 'time' is a DATETIME...

Comment: Yes, I do have it set as datetime, thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE DATE_ADD(`time`, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) < NOW()";
```

It adds two hours to your column value and if it is less then the current time it will be deleted.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf1ca/1)

Comment: no... if time is 11 and now is 12, then 11 > 12-2 is true, so it would be deleted, and that's not what was wanted...

Comment: I had to stop and think about it but you are correct. I changed the logic appropriately.

Comment: don't worry, I had to check 4 times before I was sure either... these things are always complicated, that's why I just filled in times, that makes it a lot easier to figure out...

Comment: @Shanie93 I just changed my code two minutes ago. Did you use that code? Or my original post?

Comment: Okay. I have 2 test entry's in... One from 30 minutes ago, another from 42 minutes ago. I updated my query to your edited reply, however, changing the interval to test on my more recent rows, this time I ended up with 0 rows deleted each time, I even tried 5 minutes interval

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code @Shanie93, to know for sure: in PHP, do [echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");] and in MySQL [SELECT NOW()] and compare...

Comment: The SQL fiddle seems to show my code working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf1ca/1. If you remove the `DELETE` statement you'll see both rows appear. If you leave it the one that is four hours old is deleted.

Comment: This (*answer*) worked for me, having DATETIME as a column type. @OP, make sure you do in fact have entries that are older than 2 hours or more.

Comment: Ohmy! I do apologize!! I had thought my PHP & MySQL TimeZones were the same, because they're on the same server, I'm so sorry. There's a 3 hour gap between them, It seems to be working now when I manually run it at different times on several rows, it only deletes the ones constructed to do so, you guys have saved me so much time, I really do appreciate it! now, one other thing if I may ask. How can i setup an event to run this query every 5minutes?

Comment: Look into cron jobs. They're not tough to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Are your MySQL server and your HTTPD the same machine (I know mine aren't)? 'cause you're inserting your MySQL data with times from the PHP server and then comparing with MySQL times...

Might be better to insert like this:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table(name,email,time) VALUES ('$name','$email',NOW())
```

at least that will ensure comparing the right times...

And also make sure TIME is defined as a DATETIME, not just a DATE

Comment: Yes they're on the same machine, The time stamps are identical, but to avoid confusion i've changed my insert query to yours above and works perfectly, thank you!. Now just to finish the deleting code

Comment: are you sure they're on the same time then? If this insert code fixed it your PHP is most likely set up in a different timezone from MySQL